# Class App\Repositories\UserRepository does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, repository, laravel-5.1

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory as Socialite; 
use App\Repositories\UserRepository;


class SocialController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Redirect the user to the GitHub authentication page.
     *
     * @return Response
     */

    private $socialite;
     private $auth;
     private $users;

     public function __construct(Socialite $socialite, Guard $auth, UserRepository $users) {   
        $this->socialite = $socialite;
        $this->users = $users;
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }
}
```

This is my controller. While I'm loading this controller it showing an error like

> "ReflectionException in Container.php line 791: Class App\Repositories\UserRepository does not exist".

Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Comment: Is there any solution? I am facing similar error in Laravel 5.8

Answer (score 5):

Probably a namespace issue

Check the path of your `UserRepository` file class. It should be:

```
app/Repositories/UserRepository.php
```

And inside the class file you need to use this namespace:

```
namespace App/Repositories;
```

This should work

Comment: It gives me error that (dot) cannot be used in use. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you would want to do `composer dump-autoload` and it will fix your issue 
given that you have all your namespaces / class names correctly

Answer (score 1):

**Change your composer.json file.**

"autoload": {

```
 "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
       "database",
       "app/Repositories"
 ],
```

**composer dump-autoload**

=> Done

Answer (score 0):

The strange thing I had when such error occurred is that I had space between keyword `namespace` and `App\Repositories;` Once removed, it all worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

in case seems like this, delete the vendor folder and re-install composer

```
   composer install
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your class namespace is correct or you can also run this command below

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have some syntax errors in that class, the message is the same as class not found.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is facing this error. I think, you may get this error, if your Repository class is not able to access your model, just add `use App\User;` at top and the error should go.

Answer (score 0):

I had such problem when I tried to re-install Bagisto (on Laravel). I deleted the .env file in the project root and this solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just refactor `UserRepository` class to for example `MyUserRepository` , only this one solved my problem

Comment: Could you provide a code example with this explanation?